# Freezing user input with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

In my AutoHotKey script, I want to freeze user input, i.e. any input from the user will not propagate to the active program, and then unfreeze and have all the input that the user typed go to the program.

In other words: I freeze, then the user types "xyz" but this is *not* passed to the active program, and then I unfreeze, keystrokes "xyz" are passed to the program, and then everything's back to normal and the user can type again and it'll go to the active program.

This is so while I enter a bunch of text in the program using `ControlSend`, the user's typing won't interfere.

Possible? How?

Comment: I guess I should ask, are you sending all of your text with one SendInput, or do you want to freeze (turn on the user input buffer), do several computations or loops with SendInputs in them, then unfreeze (dump the user input buffer)?

Comment: If it's possible to freeze, do a bunch of stuff, then unfreeze, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to send all of your text using one SendInput, then AutoHotkey takes care of the problem for you. From the AutoHotkey [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) documentation,

> SendInput and SendPlay [...] buffer any physical keyboard or mouse activity during the send, which prevents the user's keystrokes from being interspersed with those being sent.

If it's acceptable to lose the user input while it's frozen (instead of buffer it and send it afterward), you can use [BlockInput](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm).  Something like

```
BlockInput On
; Send desired text here
BlockInput Off
```

However, the BlockInput documentation says if it starts when keys are already down, it can block the "key up" events and cause keys to appear stuck down. So depending on when you use it, you might have to first wait for keys to be released using [KeyWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm).

Comment: But I'm using `ControlSend`, cause I'm sending to a specific control...

Comment: OK. Consider updating your question so other responders understand the full picture.

Comment: Edited answer: BlockInput may be helpful.

Comment: Nah, `BlockInput` doesn't help me.

Answer (score -2):

Use the Input command.

http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/Input.htm

**edit**

You said:

> In my AutoHotKey script, I want to freeze user input, i.e. any input
>   from the user will not propagate to the active program, and then
>   unfreeze and have all the input that the user typed go to the program.
>
> In other words: I freeze, then the user types "xyz" but this is not
>   passed to the active program, and then I unfreeze, keystrokes "xyz"
>   are passed to the program, and then everything's back to normal and
>   the user can type again and it'll go to the active program.

The Input command does:

> ; Wait for the user to press any key.  Keys that produce no visible
>   character, such as the modifier keys, function keys, and arrow keys,
>   are listed as end keys
>   so that they will be detected too.
>
> `Input, SingleKey, L1,`
>   `{LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}`

You can loop this for multiple keys or it takes a string of keys as an argument.

Comment: I did not understand at all how that would be helpful.

Comment: Let me quote the documentations.

Comment: It seems that this is intended to take input from the user. I don't want to take input from the user. In fact it's okay if the user doesn't give any input. But if he does, I want to buffer it and output it later, after I've finished sending my own input using `SendInput`. I have no idea how I could achieve that using `Input`.